# Turbo Frames Issue with jQuery Append

Tags: jquery, turbo-frames

Turbo frames are causing the jQuery script to not run if I navigate between tabs or pages. Below is my code. Any ideas on a workaround so the script continues to run even after the page url changes?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').append('<div>Sample Text</div>');
});
```

I was able to modify the script with the following from the answer below and included additional code so it would load on the initial page load as well. Not sure if it's the correct way to do it, but it works. See below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').append('<div>Sample Text</div>');
});

$(document).on("turbo:frame-load", function() {
  $('#test').append('<div>Sample Text</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, there are events that you could in theory attach to.

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events

```
$.loadContent = function() {
  $('#test').append('<div>Sample Text</div>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.loadContent();

  $(document).on("turbo:frame-render", function() {
    $.loadContent();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That got it super close. Unfortunately, it will not load the script on the first visit to the page, but when I navigate between the pages the script runs as intended. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Bronson77, I updated my answer. A simple way is to add the code to a function and run that on load and in the event handler. You can always go to that link of the events and figure out what event works for you, but my updated answer should accomplish what you are looking for